# Add method that works with either a Point Object or a tuple

Tags: python, addition, overloading

One of my exercises says to write an *add* method for Points that works with either a Point object or a tuple:

- If the second operand is a Point, the method should return a new Point whose x coordinate is the sum of the x coordinates of the operands, and likewise for the y coordinates.
- If the second operand is a tuple, the method should add the first element of the tuple to the x coordinate and the second element to the y coordinate, and return a new Point with the result.

This how far I got and I'm not sure if the tuple portion of my code is accurate. Can someone shed some light how I would call this program for the tuple portion. I think I nailed the first part.

Here is my code:

```
Class Point():
    def__add__(self,other):
            if isinstance(other,Point):
                    return self.add_point(other)
            else:
                    return self.print_point(other)

    def add_point(self,other):
            totalx = self.x + other.x
            totaly = self.y + other.y
            total = ('%d, %d') % (totalx, totaly)
            return total

    def print_point(self):
            print ('%d, %d) % (self.x, self.y)

    blank = Point()
    blank.x = 3
    blank.y = 5
    blank1 = Point()
    blank1.x = 5
    blank1.y = 6
```

That's what I've built so far and I'm not sure how to actually run this with the tuple part. I know if it did `blank + blank1` the if portion would run and call the `add_point` function but how do I initiate the tuple. I'm not sure if I wrote this correctly... please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to be able to use point.x and point.y syntax, you could implement the following:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other): 
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, tuple):
            return Point(self.x + other[0], self.y + other[1])
        else:
            raise TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Point' and '{0}'".format(type(other)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return u'Point ({0}, {1})'.format(self.x, self.y) #Remove the u if you're using Python 3
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more on the elif isinstance(other, tuple)? The return for that, please explain what that would look like if we placed a tuple?

Comment: This add method first checks whether the passed argument is a Point, and if it's not, whether it's a tuple. In both cases we instantiate a new point with the corresponding coordinates (sum of both points' x and y respectively, or using the tuple's first and second item as z and y.

Comment: I'd inherit from a tuple anyway, and made `x` and `y` properties.

Comment: That would be pretty elegant and probably a better solution indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply derive your class from the tuple (or just implement `__getitem__`).

```
class Point(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (x, y))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1])

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({0}, {1})'.format(self[0], self[1])

p = Point(1, 1)
print p + Point(5, 5) # Point(6, 6)
print p + (5, 5)      # Point(6, 6)
```